# Unable to read events in Laravel Echo

Tags: laravel, vue.js, websocket

```
"laravel-echo": "^1.6.0",
"pusher-js": "^5.0.2",
```

I am using Laravel WebSockets to send events to my Vue.js app using Laravel Echo as:
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

First of all when I connect my app, I see this message:

```
Connection id 473581849.201555836 sending message {"event":"pusher:connection_established","data":"{\"socket_id\":\"473581849.201555836\",\"activity_timeout\":30}"}
```

When I disconnect, I see this one:

```
Connection id 603442282.571320345 closed.
```

So the app is well communicating with the Laravel WebSocket, no problem with that as it received the connection and connection packets from my app.

My problem comes when I try to read in my front end a packet from the server, I just cannot get it.

```
const echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  cluster: process.env.WEBSOCKET_CLUSTER,
  key: process.env.WEBSOCKET_KEY,
  wsHost: process.env.WEBSOCKET_URL,
  wssHost: process.env.WEBSOCKET_URL,
  wsPort: process.env.WEBSOCKET_PORT,
  wssPort: process.env.WEBSOCKET_PORT,
  encrypted: process.env.WEBSOCKET_ENCRYPTED,
  disableStats: process.env.WEBSOCKET_DISABLE_STATS,
  enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
  // auth: {
  //   headers: {
  //     'Accept': 'application/json',
  //     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
  //   }
  // }
});
export default ({ Vue }) => {
  Vue.prototype.$echo = echo;
};
```

Here is for example an event received(this is what I get from the ssh console):

```
Connection id 545411452.62710705 sending message {"event":"log-message","channel":"private-websockets-dashboard-api-message","data":{"type":"api-message","time":"20:06:24","details":"Channel: androidMobile, Event: App\\Events\\UpdateAndroidNavBarCounts","data":"{\"message\":{\"countincompletereports\":0,\"countviewmyreports\":1002,\"countpoints\":300,\"user_id\":63}}"}}
```

This event here: App\Events\UpdateAndroidNavBarCounts

I cannot get it in my front end, I tried this:

```
      this.$echo.channel('androidMobile')
        .listen('.App.Events.UpdateAndroidNavBarCounts', function (data) {<------------
          console.log('This is a test 2');
          this.$store.dispatch('common/UpdateAndroidNavBarCounts', data, { root: true });
        })
```

this

```
      this.$echo.channel('androidMobile')
        .listen('App.Events.UpdateAndroidNavBarCounts', function (data) {<------------
          console.log('This is a test 2');
          this.$store.dispatch('common/UpdateAndroidNavBarCounts', data, { root: true });
        })
```

this:

```
      this.$echo.channel('androidMobile')
        .listen('.UpdateAndroidNavBarCounts', function (data) {<------------
          console.log('This is a test 2');
          this.$store.dispatch('common/UpdateAndroidNavBarCounts', data, { root: true });
        })
```

and even this:

```
      this.$echo.channel('androidMobile')
        .listen('UpdateAndroidNavBarCounts', function (data) { <------------
          console.log('This is a test 2');
          this.$store.dispatch('common/UpdateAndroidNavBarCounts', data, { root: true });
        })
```

I never managed to see the console.log('This is a test 2'); message.

Any help would be appreciated please as I have been struggling on this for days and days and I am starting to believe that it is a bug.

Thank you.

Comment: In the browser dev-tools, under network, can you see the actual websocket messages being received?

Answer (score 0):

oK, with time I worked it out ...

I was using the Quasar framework and this was the top of my boot file:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Pusher.logToConsole = true;
```

When I added this logToConsole = true; parameter, I could start seeing the communication from the Android mobile to the API.

My problem was this:

```
authEndpoint: process.env.WEBSOCKET_AUTH_URL
```

let's say WEBSOCKET_AUTH_URL = https://mywebsite.com

No idea why but if I add this:

```
authEndPoint: process.env.WEBSOCKET_AUTH_URL + '/broadcasting/auth'
```

It does not work, the url is broken into 2 strings.

I also tried this:

```
authEndPoint: JSON.stringify(process.env.WEBSOCKET_AUTH_URL) + '/broadcasting/auth'
```

No luck either, so instead I added the whole url in the .env file as:

```
WEBSOCKET_AUTH_URL = https://mywebsite.com/broadcasting/auth
```

Now it works.